# Based on this SVG how do I isolate the neck area from the head

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, path

I was attempting to improve this body rendering model.

https://github.com/volcanioo/Human-Body-Rendering-HTML

But I was trying to add some more detail. I started by isolating the neck from the head.

So I figured out that the paths for drawing the neck is this.

```
<svg data-position='neck' id='neck' class='neck' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='56.594' height='95.031' viewBox='0 0 56.594 95.031'><path d='M15.92 68.5l8.8 12.546 3.97 13.984-9.254-7.38-4.622-15.848zm27.1 0l-8.8 12.546-3.976 13.988 9.254-7.38 4.622-15.848z'/></svg>
```

But as it happens now if I try to do this it will actually block the head area from being clicked.
Screencaps don't show it but I am hovering my cursor over the head.
Also another note is that when I separate the head from the neck, the hair goes funky as shown below.

[image: Body Example]

Any help to isolate the neck from the head will be a big help.
Ill post the js, html and css files with my changes and explanations below.

```js
window.onload = function () {
    const pieces = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');
    for (var i = 0; pieces.length; i++) {
        let _piece = pieces[i];
        _piece.onclick = function(t) {
            if (t.target.getAttribute('data-position') != null) document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = t.target.getAttribute('data-position');
            if (t.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-position') != null) document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = t.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-position');
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.human-body {
    width: 207px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 240px;
    height: 260px;
    display: block;
    margin: 40px auto;
}

.human-body svg:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.human-body svg:hover path {
    fill: #ff7d16;
}

.human-body svg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    fill: #57c9d5;
}

.human-body svg#head {
    margin-left: -28.5px;
    top: -6px;
}

.human-body svg#neck {
    margin-left: -28.5px;
    top: -6px;
}

.human-body svg#left-shoulder {
    margin-left: -53.5px;
    top: 69px;
}

.human-body svg#right-shoulder {
    margin-left: 13.5px;
    top: 69px;
}

.human-body svg#left-arm {
    margin-left: -78px;
    top: 112px;
}

.human-body svg#right-arm {
    margin-left: 38px;
    top: 112px;
    z-index: 10001;
}

.human-body svg#chest {
    margin-left: -43.5px;
    top: 88px;
}

.human-body svg#stomach {
    margin-left: -37.5px;
    top: 130px;
}

.human-body svg#left-leg {
    margin-left: -46.5px;
    top: 205px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.human-body svg#right-leg {
    margin-left: 1.5px;
    top: 205px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.human-body svg#left-hand {
    margin-left: -102.5px;
    top: 224px;
}

.human-body svg#right-hand {
    margin-left: 66.5px;
    top: 224px;
    z-index: 10000;
}

.human-body svg#left-foot {
    margin-left: -35.5px;
    top: 455px;
}

.human-body svg#right-foot {
    margin-left: 5.5px;
    top: 455px;
}

#area {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: Courier New;
    color: #a5a5a5;
}

#area #data {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!-- Meta Tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Stylesheet Docs -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

    <!-- Javascript Docs -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- Human Body //-->
    <div class="human-body">
        <svg data-position='head' id='head' class='head' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='56.594' height='95.031' viewBox='0 0 56.594 95.031'><path d='m27.1 0l-8.8 12.546-3.976 13.988 9.254-7.38 4.622-15.848zm6.11-27.775l.108-11.775-21.16-14.742L8.123 26.133 8.09 40.19l-3.24.215 1.462 9.732 5.208 1.81 2.36 11.63 9.72 11.018 10.856-.324 9.56-10.37 1.918-11.952 5.207-1.81 1.342-9.517zm-43.085-1.84l-.257-13.82L28.226 11.9l23.618 15.755-.216 10.37 4.976-17.085L42.556 2.376 25.49 0 10.803 3.673.002 24.415z'/></svg>
        <svg data-position='neck' id='neck' class='neck' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='56.594' height='95.031' viewBox='0 0 56.594 95.031'><path d='M15.92 68.5l8.8 12.546 3.97 13.984-9.254-7.38-4.622-15.848zm27.1 0l-8.8 12.546-3.976 13.988 9.254-7.38 4.622-15.848z'/></svg>
        <svg data-position='left-shoulder' id='left-shoulder' class='left-shoulder' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='109.532' height='46.594' viewBox='0 0 109.532 46.594'><path d='m 38.244,-0.004 1.98,9.232 -11.653,2.857 -7.474,-2.637 z M 17.005,10.536 12.962,8.35 0.306,22.35 0.244,27.675 c 0,0 16.52,-17.015 16.764,-17.14 z m 1.285,0.58 C 18.3,11.396 0.528,30.038 0.528,30.038 L -0.01,46.595 6.147,36.045 18.017,30.989 26.374,15.6 Z'/></svg>
        <svg data-position='right-shoulder' id='right-shoulder' class='right-shoulder' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='109.532' height='46.594' viewBox='0 0 109.532 46.594'><path d='m 3.2759972,-0.004 -1.98,9.232 11.6529998,2.857 7.473999,-2.637 z m 21.2379988,10.54 4.044,-2.187 12.656,14 0.07,5.33 c 0,0 -16.524,-17.019 -16.769,-17.144 z m -1.285,0.58 c -0.008,0.28 17.762,18.922 17.762,18.922 l 0.537,16.557 -6.157,-10.55 -11.871,-5.057 L 15.147997,15.6 Z'/></svg>
        <svg data-position='left-arm' id='left-arm' class='left-arm' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='156.344' height='119.25' viewBox='0 0 156.344 119.25'><path d='m21.12,56.5a1.678,1.678 0 0 1 -0.427,0.33l0.935,8.224l12.977,-13.89l1.2,-8.958a168.2,168.2 0 0 0 -14.685,14.294zm1.387,12.522l-18.07,48.91l5.757,1.333l19.125,-39.44l3.518,-22.047l-10.33,11.244zm-5.278,-18.96l2.638,18.74l-17.2,46.023l-2.657,-1.775l6.644,-35.518l10.575,-27.47zm18.805,-12.323a1.78,1.78 0 0 1 0.407,-0.24l3.666,-27.345l-7.037,-10.139l-7.258,10.58l-6.16,37.04l0.566,4.973a151.447,151.447 0 0 1 15.808,-14.87l0.008,0.001zm-13.742,-28.906l-3.3,35.276l-2.2,-26.238l5.5,-9.038z'/></svg>
        <svg data-position='right-arm' id='right-arm' class='right-arm' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='156.344' height='119.25' viewBox='0 0 156.344 119.25'><path d='m 18.997,56.5 a 1.678,1.678 0 0 0 0.427,0.33 L 18.489,65.054 5.512,51.164 4.312,42.206 A 168.2,168.2 0 0 1 18.997,56.5 Z m -1.387,12.522 18.07,48.91 -5.757,1.333 L 10.798,79.825 7.28,57.778 17.61,69.022 Z m 5.278,-18.96 -2.638,18.74 17.2,46.023 2.657,-1.775 L 33.463,77.532 22.888,50.062 Z M 4.083,37.739 A 1.78,1.78 0 0 0 3.676,37.499 L 0.01,10.154 7.047,0.015 l 7.258,10.58 6.16,37.04 -0.566,4.973 A 151.447,151.447 0 0 0 4.091,37.738 l -0.008,10e-4 z m 13.742,-28.906 3.3,35.276 2.2,-26.238 -5.5,-9.038 z'/></svg>
        <svg data-position='chest' id='chest' class='chest' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='86.594' height='45.063' viewBox='0 0 86.594 45.063'><path d='M19.32 0l-9.225 16.488-10.1 5.056 6.15 4.836 4.832 14.07 11.2 4.616 17.85-8.828-4.452-34.7zm47.934 0l9.225 16.488 10.1 5.056-6.15 4.836-4.833 14.07-11.2 4.616-17.844-8.828 4.45-34.7z'/></svg>
        <svg data-position='stomach' id='stomach' class='stomach' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='75.25' height='107.594' viewBox='0 0 75.25 107.594'><path d='M19.25 7.49l16.6-7.5-.5 12.16-14.943 7.662zm-10.322 8.9l6.9 3.848-.8-9.116zm5.617-8.732L1.32 2.15 6.3 15.6zm-8.17 9.267l9.015 5.514 1.54 11.028-8.795-5.735zm15.53 5.89l.332 8.662 12.286-2.665.664-11.826zm14.61 84.783L33.28 76.062l-.08-20.53-11.654-5.736-1.32 37.5zM22.735 35.64L22.57 46.3l11.787 3.166.166-16.657zm-14.16-5.255L16.49 35.9l1.1 11.25-8.8-7.06zm8.79 22.74l-9.673-7.28-.84 9.78L-.006 68.29l10.564 14.594 5.5.883 1.98-20.735zM56 7.488l-16.6-7.5.5 12.16 14.942 7.66zm10.32 8.9l-6.9 3.847.8-9.116zm-5.617-8.733L73.93 2.148l-4.98 13.447zm8.17 9.267l-9.015 5.514-1.54 11.03 8.8-5.736zm-15.53 5.89l-.332 8.662-12.285-2.665-.664-11.827zm-14.61 84.783l3.234-31.536.082-20.532 11.65-5.735 1.32 37.5zm13.78-71.957l.166 10.66-11.786 3.168-.166-16.657zm14.16-5.256l-7.915 5.514-1.1 11.25 8.794-7.06zm-8.79 22.743l9.673-7.28.84 9.78 6.862 12.66-10.564 14.597-5.5.883-1.975-20.74z'/></svg>
        <svg data-position='left-leg' id='left-leg' class='left-leg' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='93.626' height='250.625' viewBox='0 0 93.626 250.625'><path d='m 18.00179,139.99461 -0.664,5.99 4.647,5.77 1.55,9.1 3.1,1.33 2.655,-13.755 1.77,-4.88 -1.55,-3.107 z m 20.582,0.444 -3.32,9.318 -7.082,13.755 1.77,12.647 5.09,-14.2 4.205,-7.982 z m -26.557,-12.645 5.09,27.29 -3.32,-1.777 -2.656,8.875 z m 22.795,42.374 -1.55,4.88 -3.32,20.634 -0.442,27.51 4.65,26.847 -0.223,-34.39 4.87,-13.754 0.663,-15.087 z m -10.623,12.424 1.106,41.267 c 14.157565,64.57987 -5.846437,10.46082 -16.8199998,-29.07 l 5.5329998,-36.384 z m -9.71,-178.164003 0,22.476 15.71,31.073 9.923,30.850003 -1.033,-21.375 z m 25.49,30.248 0.118,-0.148 -0.793,-2.024 -16.545,-18.16 -1.242,-0.44 10.984,28.378 z m -6.255,10.766 6.812,17.6 2.274,-21.596 -1.344,-3.43 z m -26.4699998,17.82 0.827,25.340003 12.8159998,35.257 -3.928,10.136 -12.6099998,-44.51 z M 31.81879,76.04161 l 0.345,0.826 6.47,15.48 -4.177,38.342 -6.594,-3.526 5.715,-35.7 z m -21.465,-74.697003 0.827,21.373 L 4.1527902,65.02561 0.84679017,30.870607 Z m 2.068,27.323 14.677,32.391 3.307,26.000003 -6.2,36.58 -13.437,-37.241 -0.8269998,-38.342003 z'/></svg>
        <svg data-position='right-leg' id='right-leg' class='right-leg' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='80' height='250.625' viewBox='0 0 80 250.625'><path d='m 26.664979,139.7913 0.663,5.99 -4.647,5.77 -1.55,9.1 -3.1,1.33 -2.655,-13.755 -1.77,-4.88 1.55,-3.107 z m -20.5820002,0.444 3.3200005,9.318 7.0799997,13.755 -1.77,12.647 -5.0899997,-14.2 -4.2000005,-7.987 z m 3.7620005,29.73 1.5499997,4.88 3.32,20.633 0.442,27.51 -4.648,26.847 0.22,-34.39 -4.8670002,-13.754 -0.67,-15.087 z m 10.6229997,12.424 -1.107,41.267 -8.852,33.28 9.627,-4.55 16.046,-57.8 -5.533,-36.384 z m -13.9460002,74.991 c -5.157661,19.45233 -2.5788305,9.72616 0,0 z M 30.177979,4.225305 l 0,22.476 -15.713,31.072 -9.9230002,30.850005 1.033,-21.375005 z m -25.4930002,30.249 -0.118,-0.15 0.793,-2.023 16.5450002,-18.16 1.24,-0.44 -10.98,28.377 z m 6.2550002,10.764 -6.8120002,17.6 -2.274,-21.595 1.344,-3.43 z m 26.47,17.82 -0.827,25.342005 -12.816,35.25599 3.927,10.136 12.61,-44.50999 z m -24.565,12.783005 -0.346,0.825 -6.4700002,15.48 4.1780002,38.34199 6.594,-3.527 -5.715,-35.69999 z m 19.792,51.74999 -5.09,27.29 3.32,-1.776 2.655,8.875 z m 1.671,-126.452995 -0.826,21.375 7.03,42.308 3.306,-34.155 z m -2.066,27.325 -14.677,32.392 -3.308,26.000005 6.2,36.57999 13.436,-37.23999 0.827,-38.340005 z'/></svg>
        <svg data-position='left-hand' id='left-hand' class='left-hand' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='90' height='38.938' viewBox='0 0 90 38.938'><path d='m 21.255,-0.00198191 2.88,6.90000201 8.412,1.335 0.664,12.4579799 -4.427,17.8 -2.878,-0.22 2.8,-11.847 -2.99,-0.084 -4.676,12.6 -3.544,-0.446 4.4,-12.736 -3.072,-0.584 -5.978,13.543 -4.428,-0.445 6.088,-14.1 -2.1,-1.25 L 4.878,34.934 1.114,34.489 12.4,12.9 11.293,11.12 0.665,15.57 0,13.124 8.635,5.3380201 Z' /></svg>
        <svg data-position='right-hand' id='right-hand' class='right-hand' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='90' height='38.938' viewBox='0 0 90 38.938'><path d='m 13.793386,-0.00198533 -2.88,6.90000163 -8.4120002,1.335 -0.664,12.4579837 4.427,17.8 2.878,-0.22 -2.8,-11.847 2.99,-0.084 4.6760002,12.6 3.544,-0.446 -4.4,-12.736 3.072,-0.584 5.978,13.543 4.428,-0.445 -6.088,-14.1 2.1,-1.25 7.528,12.012 3.764,-0.445 -11.286,-21.589 1.107,-1.78 10.628,4.45 0.665,-2.447 -8.635,-7.7859837 z'/></svg>
        <svg data-position='left-foot' id='left-foot' class='left-foot' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30' height='30' viewBox='0 0 30 30'><path d='m 19.558357,1.92821 c -22.1993328,20.55867 -11.0996668,10.27933 0,0 z m 5.975,5.989 -0.664,18.415 -1.55,6.435 -4.647,0 -1.327,-4.437 -1.55,-0.222 0.332,4.437 -5.864,-1.778 -1.5499998,-0.887 -6.64,-1.442 -0.22,-5.214 6.418,-10.87 4.4259998,-5.548 c 9.991542,-3.26362 9.41586,-8.41457 12.836,1.111 z'/></svg>
        <svg data-position='right-foot' id='right-foot' class='right-foot' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='90' height='38.938' viewBox='0 0 90 38.938'><path d='m 11.723492,2.35897 c -40.202667,20.558 -20.1013335,10.279 0,0 z m -5.9740005,5.989 0.663,18.415 1.546,6.435 4.6480005,0 1.328,-4.437 1.55,-0.222 -0.333,4.437 5.863,-1.778 1.55,-0.887 6.638,-1.442 0.222,-5.214 -6.418,-10.868 -4.426,-5.547 -10.8440005,-4.437 z'/> </svg>
    </div>
    <!--// Human Body -->

    <!-- Data Showing //-->
    <div id="area">
        Area: <span id="data"></span>
    </div>
    <!--// Data Showing -->

</body>
</html>
```

index.js - No changes have been made as the JS doesn't affect the functionality.

index.css - I have made changes to this, I added the section for the neck. I have played with the margin left and top value to see if it fixes the neck problems to no avail.

index.html - The only change I have made here was removing the path for the neck section and adding it to its own element.
I have played with the viewbox size as well as the necks own width and height so that head can be clicked but it seems to either disappear or not do anything.

The uncaught typeError shouldn't stop you from seeing it not working.

Any help from any web dev wizards would be fantastic.
Ill be floating around to answer any clarifications.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry to say this is outside the scope of what is doable within the format of a SO answer. The way the authors choose to construct this makes editing a lot of fiddly work, and any sane way to edit it would mean one had to rewrite it more or less from scratch.

Comment: @ccprog Thanks, ill try and build it from scratch